# Возможно ли прочитать файл с конкретного места С

Tags: c, файлы, input, io, filestream

Суть такая: имеется файл (допустим 1000 строк) и мне нужно прочитать строку №500. Есть ли способ сразу обратиться к конкретной строке???

Comment: Если вы знаете, с какого байта она начинается.

Comment: @Harry то есть допустим строки фиксированной длины (размера) и для получения 500-ой длина строки * 500

Comment: Ну это если те самые 500 байтов включают и символ(ы) конца строки. Тогда `fseek()`.

Comment: Если строки разной длины, то никак, только читать последовательно. Но если хранить строки не просто в файле, а организовать строки в базу данных, то можно. А еще проще - хранить 1000 строк в 1000 отдельных файлов. Если нужна строка номер 500, то просто читаете 500-й файл. :-)

Comment: В общем дальнейшие итерации приведут к созданию базы данных :) Разумнее делать 2 файла, один с индексом строк, другой со строками, в первом хранить фиксированную структуру с указателем офсета начала строки и ее длинна, или офсет конца строки - как удобнее..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если строки фиксированной длины, то вы можете вычислить позицию, с которой начинается данная строка (грубо говоря, `len*500`), после чего установить указатель файла в нужную позицию (функция `fseek(f,pos,SEEK_SET)`, раз у вас С) и считать то, что вам нужно.

Файл я бы при этом открывал как бинарный.

Ну, е если все строки разные и у вас нет информации об их размерах - чтоб вычислить позицию начала N-й строки - то только чтением подряд до нужной строки.